# Подгрузка html шаблона

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как правильно  организовать загрузку `html` файла  средствами  `js`. Т.е на сервере есть `html-шаблон`. Его нужно подтянуть, сделать модификацию и вывести в браузер.

Comment: `$.get('aboutl.html', function(data){
   elem.innerHTML = data;
});`? Но надо **jQuery**

Comment: спасибо. за ответ  сохранил к себе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал как-то так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", success: function(result){
     // здесь обрабатываем загруженную страницу                
     $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Допустим в шаблоне есть  какой то тег с  id   могули в него что то записать  до отрисовки? или лутше будит после  добавить нужные мне изменения ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="loaded-template"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#loaded-template').load('template.html');
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ сохранил к себе